# Test explorer empty in VS2015 CE Update 3 with xUnit

Tags: xunit, visual-studio-2015

I just upgraded VS2015 CE to Update 3 and realized that Test Explorer stopped working properly.
I had 3 test projects, all of them with these NuGet packages:

```
<package id="Castle.Core" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="FluentAssertions" version="4.12.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="MediatR" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Moq" version="4.5.16" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="xunit" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="xunit.assert" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="xunit.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="xunit.runner.console" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

everything was working fine but now after the update I cannot see the tests. Any advice?

UPDATE:
re-installed VS. Nothing changed. But I noticed that the Test console says that an exception occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.UI.TestWindowToolWindowControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed in new update.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx

If use not English version VS 2015 Update 3, also can help change language to English.

Comment: worked perfectly thank you. I installed the same update a couple of weeks ago but turns out they uploaded a new version.